# How can I simplify this code to compute the shortest rotation between two angles?

Tags: c++, mathematics, rotation, floating-point

The following code will find the shortest rotation (in radians) (from pi to -pi) that I need to apply to `from` to leave me with `to`.

```
Scalar rotationBetween(Scalar from, Scalar to)
{
    Scalar fromMod = std::signbit(from) ? 
        pi * 2 + std::fmod(from, pi * 2) : std::fmod(from, pi * 2);
    Scalar toMod = std::signbit(to) ?
        pi * 2 + std::fmod(to, pi * 2) : std::fmod(to, pi * 2);

    Scalar rotation = toMod - fromMod;

    if(rotation > pi)
        return rotation - 2 * pi;
    else if(rotation < -pi)
        return 2 * pi + rotation;
    else
        return rotation;
}
```

`Scalar` is a c++ `float`.

Can I simplify this? I feel like this is far too much logic to do something so simple.

Comment: `std::min(std::max(from, to) - std::min(from,to), std::min(from,to) + 2*pi - std::max(from,to));`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a value inside `[-pi,pi]`, you can add `pi`, do `fmod`, and subtract `pi` again. Here is one way that works. Unfortunately you still need to somehow test whether `from - to` is positive or negative before calling `fmod`:

```
Scalar rotationBetween(Scalar from, Scalar to)
{
    return (from > to) ? -pi + std::fmod(from - to + pi, pi * 2)
                       :  pi - std::fmod(to - from + pi, pi * 2);
}
```

If you are *absolutely sure* that `from` and `to` are in `[-2pi,2pi]`, then this simpler version will work:

```
Scalar rotationBetween(Scalar from, Scalar to)
{
    std::fmod(from - to + 5 * pi, pi * 2) - pi;
}
```

Finally, if you just want short code and don’t care about performance, this can be interesting:

```
Scalar rotationBetween(Scalar from, Scalar to)
{
    return 2 * std::atan(std::tan((from - to) / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do the trick.

(**Edit:** as pointed out in the comments, this gives the unsigned rotation).

```
Scalar rotationBetween(Scalar from, Scalar to)
{
   //Calculates the two possibilities, and take the smallest
   Scalar difference = std::min(
      std::fmod(from - to, pi * 2),
      std::fmod(to - from, pi * 2)); 

   //takes the above that is in the range 0 to 2*pi 
   //and brings it in the range -pi to pi
   if (difference > pi) 
      difference -= 2 * pi;

   return difference;
}
```

Comment: This cannot be correct. It returns the same value for `rotationBetween(a,b)` and `rotationBetween(b,a)`.

Comment: @sam But the min angle between a an b is the same angle between b and a. Look at a clock. Is the big hand / little hand different from the little hand and the big???

Comment: They are the same in absolute value, but the sign matters, too. `rotationBetween(0,1)` should return `1` but it is expected that `rotationBetween(1,0)` returns `-1`.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes it trickier.